# How to establish bidirectional relationships on tables with multiple join paths in SQLALchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

The example given in [sqlalchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths) is,

```
from sqlalchemy import Integer, ForeignKey, String, Column
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()

class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'customer'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    billing_address_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("address.id"))
    shipping_address_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("address.id"))

    billing_address = relationship("Address", foreign_keys=[billing_address_id])
    shipping_address = relationship("Address", foreign_keys=[shipping_address_id])

class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    street = Column(String)
    city = Column(String)
    state = Column(String)
    zip = Column(String)
```

I am trying a similar example (cannot place so much code here) it does not work if I do something similar to this:

```
from sqlalchemy import Integer, ForeignKey, String, Column
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()

class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'customer'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    billing_address_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("address.id"))
    shipping_address_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("address.id"))

    billing_address = relationship("Address", foreign_keys=[billing_address_id], back_populates('bill_addr'))
    shipping_address = relationship("Address", foreign_keys=[shipping_address_id], back_populates('ship_addr'))

class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    street = Column(String)
    city = Column(String)
    state = Column(String)
    zip = Column(String)

    bill_addr = relationship("Customer", back_populates('billing_address'))
    ship_addr = relationship("Customer", back_populates('shipping_address'))
```

I have two doubts:
Q1) Is the above relationship bidirectional?
Q2) How to establish a bidirectional relationship between tables with multiple join paths?

edit:
In my case I am getting the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables
on relationship User.expenses - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.
Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a
foreign key reference to the parent table.
```

Answer (score 1):

It is working if I used 'backref' instead of 'back_populates'. I placed the 'backref' in the relationships on the side where both the foreign keys are present and removed the relationships on the other table.